Why this idea to generate the primes in Haskell doesn't seem to work?
I'm trying to use the Sieve of Eratosthenes' algorithm in Haskell to generate a stream of primes but the code doesn't seems to work. This is the main idea.
The main idea is derived from our functional programming lectures, which in turn refer to Melissa O’Neil's paper, "The Genuine Sieve of Eratosthenes," JFC, 2009, which discussed what the sieve of Eratosthenes truly is in Haskell.
union :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
union xs@(x:txs) ys@(y:tys)
    | x < y = x:union txs ys
    | x > y = y:union xs tys
    -- se sono uguali, ne scrivo uno solo
    | otherwise = x:union txs tys

minus :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
minus xs@(x:txs) ys@(y:tys)
    | x < y = x : minus txs ys
    | x > y = y : minus xs tys
    | otherwise = x : minus xs ys    

unionP :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
unionP (x:xs) ys = x:union xs ys -- poi si va con union

unionAll :: [[Integer]] -> [Integer]
unionAll = foldr1 unionP

primes :: [Integer]
primes = 2:[3..] `minus` composites 
    where composites = unionAll [map (p*) [p..] | p <-primes]

-- Test
firstPrimes = take 15 primes    


This is what actually happened, it doesn't go beyond this:
ghci> firstPrimes [2


So i had to interrupt the process:
ghci> firstPrimes [2^CInterrupted. 
ghci>


Please always use type signatures. Also, 2 : [3..]`minus`composited is a lot clearer than the version with more whitespace around the higher-precedence operator.

It looks like unionAll is used to take an infinite amount of sorted lists and produce the sorted list of their union. I can't see how that could possibly work, even with laziness. To emit an element x the function needs to be sure that the first element of all the lists is larger than x, which can't be checked in finite time. Maybe you need a stronger precondition (e.g. a sorted() list of infinitely many sorted lists, where () uses some special order), and a smarter unionAll (foldr1 does not suffice, AFAICS).

First, your implementation of minus is wrong.  O'Neill's paper uses:
(x:xs) `minus` (y:ys) | x < y = x:(xs `minus` (y:ys))
                      | x == y = xs `minus` ys
                      | x > y = (x:xs) `minus` ys

Converting to your notation, it should look like this:
minus :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
minus xs@(x:txs) ys@(y:tys)
    | x < y = x : minus txs ys
    | x > y = minus xs tys
    | otherwise = minus txs ys

Second, the definition of union in O'Neill's paper uses foldr not foldr1, so it's equivalent to:
unionAll = foldr unionP []

instead of:
unionAll = foldr1 unionP

That may not seem like a big deal, but simple definitions of these functions look like this:
foldr f (x:xs) = f x (foldr f xs)
foldr f []     = []

foldr1 f [x]    = [x]
foldr1 f (x:xs) = f x (foldr1 f xs)

See how, for foldr1, the case for [x] comes before the case for (x:xs)?  For an infinite input list, the case [x] never occurs, but Haskell still checks the case [x] before handling the case (x:xs).  This makes foldr1 slightly less lazy than foldr.
For example:
λ> head $ foldr unionP [] ([1]:undefined)
1
λ> head $ foldr1 unionP ([1]:undefined)
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  undefined, called at <interactive>:86:27 in interactive:Ghci4

In your composites call, where unionAll is called on the infinite list of lists:
bigList = [map (p*) [p..] | p <- primes]

because of the way foldr1 is defined, Haskell can't actually return the first element from unionAll bigList until it has checked that bigList has more than one element, but this requires ensuring that there's a second element in the list:
primes = 2 : ([3..] `minus` composites)

and this requires checking that the following list is non-empty:
[3..] `minus` composites

and that requires making sure that composites starts with a number greater than 3, but that requires evaluating:
unionAll bigList

which is what started the whole computation, and you get an infinite loop.
Anyway, all you need to do to fix this is replace:
unionAll = foldr1 unionP

with the slightly lazier:
unionAll = foldr unionP []

and it should work.
Here's a full working version of your code with the corrections to minus and unionAll that generates primes without getting stuck:
union :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
union xs@(x:txs) ys@(y:tys)
    | x < y = x:union txs ys
    | x > y = y:union xs tys
    | otherwise = x:union txs tys

minus :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
minus xs@(x:txs) ys@(y:tys)
    | x < y = x : minus txs ys
    | x > y = minus xs tys
    | otherwise = minus txs ys

unionP :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
unionP (x:xs) ys = x:union xs ys -- poi si va con union

unionAll :: [[Integer]] -> [Integer]
unionAll = foldr unionP []

primes :: [Integer]
primes = 2:[3..] `minus` composites
    where composites = unionAll [map (p*) [p..] | p <- primes]

-- Test
firstPrimes = take 15 primes

